# Pandas. Which is the best way of "shifting" the n ulterior row values into precedent row values? (multiplying columns-1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, shift

In the first case, **the grouping of rows is two**, but the idea would be to generalize it for grouping of N rows.

The idea is to turn this:

```
df

    x1  x2  x3  y
0   1   2   3   NaN
1   5   6   7   8
2   9   10  11  12
3   13  14  15  16
4   17  18  19  NaN
```

into this:

```
df_grouped2
    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  y
0   1   2   3   5   6   7   8
1   5   6   7   9   10  11  12
2   9   10  11  13  14  15  16
3   13  14  15  17  18  19  NaN
```

If we group the original df with 3 rows get:

```
df_grouped3


    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9  y
0   1   2   3   5   6   7   9   10  11  12
1   5   6   7   9   10  11  13  14  15  16
2   9   10  11  13  14  15  17  18  19  NaN
```

I can't find a function or way to do this. I'm trying to create a function to do it, but the ideas that come in my mind are **iteratively and exhaustively** (looping all through the dataset).

I don't know if some combination of pandas functions like "pivot" or "shift" can be done in a **simpler way**.

Some idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `NaN` the value `np.nan` or the string `'NaN'`? Also, are you looking to shift every 5 rows into 4 rows like that, i.e. do you have multiple blocks of similar 4 rows?

Comment: Are you simply looking for `df.shift(-1)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, the NaN is "not a number" or np.nan. In this particular case that is grouped from to 2 rows, yes, df goes from 5 rows to 4, but if in this example we group from to 3 rows, the final df would go from 5 to 3 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let x be the original data frame,

```
z = x.shift(-1)
z.columns = ['x4','x5','x6','y']
col = set(x.columns)
col.remove('y')
xt = x[col]
pd.concat([xt,z],axis=1,sort=False).iloc[:-1]
```

For N = 3:

```
z2 = x.shift(-2)
z2.columns = ['x7','x8','x9','y']
col = set(z.columns)
col.remove('y')
zt = z[col]
pd.concat([xt,zt,z2],axis=1,sort=False).iloc[:-2]
```

> Note: For generation N ,  use  x.shift(-1) , x.shift(-2) until
>   x.shift(-(N-1)), You can implement this using a for loop

Answer (score 1):

@Nonamecpp

Thanks! Nice approach, following that idea, i tried to generalize that into a function, but i have a problem and i cant see de solution.

When I run the function for more than two row groupings, the output generates wrong columns (with unnecessary row values).

The function:

```
def move(df,row_agruped):

    while row_agruped > 2:
        df = move(df,2)
        row_agruped = row_agruped-1

    x = df
    z = x.shift(-1)

    num_cols = len(x.columns)

    rng = range(num_cols, num_cols-1 +((num_cols)))


    new_cols = ['x'+str(i) for i in rng] + ['y']

    z.columns = new_cols

    xt = x.iloc[:,:len(x.columns)-1]

    return pd.concat([xt,z],axis=1,sort=False).iloc[:((row_agruped)-3)]
```

For N=3 the function returns this:

```
move(x,3)


    x1  x2  x3  x4    x5    x6    x7    x8    x9    x10     x11     x12    y
0   1   2   3   5.0   6.0   7.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   9.0     10.0    11.0   12
1   5   6   7   9.0   10.0  11.0  9.0   10.0  11.0  13.0    14.0    15.0   16
2   9   10  11  13.0  14.0  15.0  13.0  14.0  15.0  17.0    18.0    19.0   NaN
```

(Note the errors in columns x4 == x7, x5 == x8, x6 == x9)

But it should return this:

```
    x1  x2  x3  x4      x5      x6      x7      x8      x9      y
0   1   2   3   5.0     6.0     7.0     9.0     10.0    11.0    12
1   5   6   7   9.0     10.0    11.0    13.0    14.0    15.0    16
2   9   10  11  13.0    14.0    15.0    17.0    18.0    19.0    NaN
```